# How to deal with a colleague who keeps making careless errors

Tags: distractions

I work with this colleague whose job is to prepare a report document, and my job is to review it, and add comments if there are any mistakes (grammar issues, logical, etc). Once they follow up on my comments I have another look, and if it's good I send out the report, and if there are more issues left, I will send it back to them. This repeats until all issues are resolved.

With almost everyone else in the team, this process is really smooth, and pointing out the mistakes usually results in them being resolved most of them time. However, with this person, if I send them 50 comments, at least 10 of them will be simply missed, and for other 20 they will introduce new mistakes. And I am not talking about something complex here. For example:

- I ask them to capitalize word 'this' since it starts from new sentence, and instead they will capitalize word 'this' which appears to also be in the middle sentence.
- I will ask them to describe 3 concrete items, and they will describe just 1 or 2.
- I will ask them make plural out of "driver identifies", and their corrected version is "drivers identifies".

And this stuff happens all the time. Keep in mind, I emphasized multiple times to accurately re-read what they write and try to be attentive, however apparently this has absolutely no affect. Sometimes we have to send the same document back and forth 10 times before they manage to finally fix all the mistakes.

This person is also native English, so it's not a matter of having poor English skills, and they are given plenty of time to complete their work, so it's not like I am shouting over their shoulder. It's also a well regarded IT firm, so they are at least somewhat intelligent and have several years of work experience. I also have feeling that they actually trying to make it good, but it just never works for them. Several times we tried fixing my pointed mistakes together in person, and they simply keep making new mistakes right in front of me. As if they are not capable of re-reading text and looking at a bigger picture.

What could it be? Is there a way of fixing this somehow? I heard that people with dyslexia have similar symptoms, but I would expect if given ample time and asked to re-read their work, they would eventually get it right. This person does not.

---

**Edit**: I am the supervisor of this person.

Comment: Are you this person's team lead or supervisor ?

Comment: Is this person working on multiple tasks at the same time (per their manager's request) ?

Comment: Yes I'm their supervisor and yes they have multiple projects at once. But that's not an excuse because everyone here has many things going at once and they can perform this task just fine. Also they have enough time for their tasks.

Comment: I know it's not a perfect solution, but I'd probably ask them to use a spell-checker/grammar checker (if it's allowed at your company). Otherwise, I think you may want to consider firing such an employee.

Comment: Okay, based on the subject of the post, with the utmost of respect, I'm slightly weirded out by the several grammatical errors in the original question here. Which brings to mind a few questions: (1) In what part of the world is this located? (2) Are most employees at the company native English speakers, or something else? (3) Is the OP a native English speaker?

Comment: ... (4) When you say, "This person is also native English", do you literally mean the person is _native English_ (i.e., from England in the United Kingdom), or that they are a _native English speaker_?

Comment: @user1880405 - The grammatical mistakes you describe suggest their written skills align with your expectations. Some of the errors you describe are learned in grade school.  Certain tools exist to can help with the more complex rules in the English language.  I use them to identify times when something is unclear or using the correct tense or tools to simple rewrite a sentence for me.

Comment: Have you considered that the person might be slightly dyslexic? My partner is mildly dyslexic: they are a very smart person but there is no way they could do this job, no matter how the hard they try .They just can't

Comment: This day and age, the setup seems a little odd. First of all a good spell and grammar checker should take care of most of this. In Google docs you can simultaneously edit the same document: no need to send stuff back and forth. For smaller changes you can just fix it yourself, which would be much faster then writing a comment about it. You trace and resolve comments and track changes. I think a little technology could go a long way here.

Comment: Folks are suggesting dyslexia, but to me it sounds like maybe the document is not particularly important and your direct report has decided to give it low priority. Is it for internal use only? Does the report, as written, function as intended or do you just demand a level of prose quality?

Comment: For the mistake of not capitalizing "this" at the start of a sentence, this seems really odd.  Is this just one example of many such grammatical mistakes?  Did the coworker change **all** instances of "this" in the document to be capitalized (e.g. a lazy global search & replace)?  Have you actually asked why your coworker did the incorrect capitalization twice?  Given how basic this is to understanding English it seems worthwhile to ask and really **listen** as to what's going on, why this particular error is occurring.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins it's in Europe, I am not native English spekaers and that person is from UK, so they are. Curious why does it matter that my questions had grammatical errors though?

Comment: @DaveG, exactly, that happens often, and they changed only once instance of 'this'. I believe it's because for every single thing they are asked to do, they immediately rush doing that without taking a second to think and re-read. Once we were fixing things together in person and they would make multiple mistakes in front of me because they act immediately on every single comment without taking a minute to think what is exactly asked. Thing is that I asked them multiple times to slow down and think/read what they say.

Comment: Question: Given that this question itself contains many spelling/grammar errors, by what metric/evidence are you certain that the person in question is a native English speaker?  Note that there are many people who have "native"-level qualification scores on tests like TOEIC and TOEFL who can't actually have a basic conversation in English, so if your metric is test scoring, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @Hilmar, we are using grammar checker but sometimes errors are still left. The problem here is that person is so inattentive that they don't even notice spell check recommendations. Of course I can fix issues myself, but idea of this process is that person improves. If I were to fix his mistakes he will not have any incentive to improve or do them less.

Comment: Roughly what percentage of the comments you send back to this person are already being picked up and reported by whatever standard spelling & grammar check is already built-in to the software being used (Word, Google Docs, whatever ...)? Are you pointing out new errors, or reiterating errors which the software is already highlighting? If a significant amount of the errors are already being highlighted, then perhaps you should simply reply with something like "don't send me this document again until all the software-highlighted errors have been resolved.".

Comment: @user1880405: Thanks for the reply. Respectfully, if the employee is a native speaker and you're not, and you're making regular grammar errors here, and you think there are errors when the grammar software doesn't -- I feel there's at least the possibility that the employee is sometimes right when you're not, and they've decided to mindlessly follow orders that sometimes don't make sense.

Comment: @Ertai87 Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear. By "native English" I means they were born and raised in UK and they speak perfect English as far as verbal goes. But that's besides the point in my opinion. Most of the errors are not because he does not know how to write in good grammar. It's that he does not put any effort in making sure it looks good.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Respectfully, that's not the case. I am not claiming my English is great but it's good enough to find mistakes. Secondly, many of the errors are not even grammar related. Forgetting commas, adding spaces in a wrong place, capitalizing the wrong word, messing up the structure of bullet point are all examples of the stuff they constantly do wrong. Also note, that they are the only person in the team who has this problem to this extend. I work with dozens of other people, in exactly same way, and none of them perform this badly.

Comment: @user1880405 As I wrote in my answer, for a native English speaker, it is in fact more difficult to write using improper grammar than it is to write using proper grammar.  Some people make minor errors such as writing "lose" as "loose", but the types and volume of errors you are describing would not be something a native speaker would do out of "carelessness", in my opinion.

Comment: "This person is also native English, so it's not a matter of having poor English skills" - bit of a logic leap there perhaps?

Answer (score 10):

Some suggestions:

1. Have a professional meeting with this person (as you are his supervisor).
2. Tell him that his repeated mistakes have created serious problems for
   you. You can no longer just let these
   mistakes happen over and over again because they distract you from your other work, slow you down considerably, and
   take you too much time to help him fixing it.
3. In that meeting, set up the **well-defined and measurable goals** for
   him to reduce the errors and the time to fix the errors. Give him a copy of these goals.
4. Tell him these goals will be some of the main criteria to measure
   his performance and promotion by the year end.
5. Ask him exactly why he makes so many mistakes in the reports he
   does. Find out if he has any disability or medical condition that
   affects his performance. If he does have a disability, then try to figure out a way to help him improve.
6. If possible, assign some senior team members to help him proof-read the reports
   before he could send them to you.
7. Regarding simple spelling and grammar errors in his reports, you can ask him to use
   many softwares to detect and fix the errors automatically. (One of these softwares is **grammarly**.)

Comment: Regarding #5: the person might have an undiagnosed condition (e.g. ADHD, dyslexia). In this case, how do you suggest they seek a diagnosis? This is probably a different question altogether.

Comment: @zmike, Yes, you are right. It is a very legitimate question and should be asked in a different question. Employers can't force employees to seek a diagnosis.

Comment: @zmike If they don't have a diagnosis and don't want one, then I believe the employer can still expect "regular" performance from the employee, and it's on them to claim they need accommodations.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like this employee is not writing in their native language and dialect, but in one they are not yet fully comfortable with. Or they're dealing with a communications disability such as dyslexia, or an attention disorder such as ADHD.

If language is the issue, and their work is good otherwise, suggesting that they take a few more-advanced language classes (and offering to pay for them) would be the most direct and complete solution.

If they have the language skills, but simply have trouble applying them, grammar checkers can help. Like spell checkers (spill chuckers?) they aren't a complete solution but will help catch and correct some of the most common errors.

It may also be possible to diagnose patterns of errors and focus on fixing those, which might be more productive than fixing each instance one at a time.

In some cases, the answer may have to be to require that every submission be checked by someone else. That's best practice in any case, and will help catch errors of fact as well as language.

But it is appropriate, and necessary, to point out that this_is_ a problem with their productivity, and a solution must be found or you will have trouble recommending they advance in the company.

I know people whose typing and spelling are awful unless they think the document is important. I have a friend whose email sometimes verges on unreadable -- not because they can't do better, but because they were part of the generation that was taught to write phonetically first and then taught proper spelling, and when in a rush the early habit pops up again, and they're impatient with spell-checkers. For them, the important thing has been to help them understand that in professional situations they MUST write professionally or they'll be assumed to be careless or worse -- Not a Good Look.

If necessary, consider assigning them to tasks where well-written English is not as important a skill. If you can't, and they can't correct the situation despite your having made "reasonable accommodations", you may have to let them go entirely.

Answer (score 3):

You've said that you supervise a number of staff who perform this kind of work.

Is producing these reports this staffer's main role, or just one of many tasks to which they could be deployed? Are they reliable with other responsibilities?

**Redistribute the work**

The reason I ask is because, if there is room for redistribution of work, then you can deal with the problem by allocating people to the things they are found in practice to be good at, and not to the things they aren't.

**On attention to detail**

Not everyone has the necessary attention to detail for a wide variety of tasks - especially tasks relating to administration. It's a cognitive skill potentially influenced by a lot of things.

This includes long-term skills development such as experience of what details are relevant, perceptual skills relating to a particular kind of work, and habitual pride and vestment in the work which drives close attention, scrutiny, and learning.

A person who doesn't experience that kind of engagement will never develop the capability.

I also wouldn't underestimate how far some people can get without paying much attention, or how compelled some people feel to pass through education, to enter a particular occupation, or to stick at a particular career, without much direct interest in it.

Employers also often employ young workers in relatively undemanding roles. And certainly in IT, I've known many to get by without written communication skills. So a "few years of work experience" says little in regard to capability.

On a more day-to-day basis, a person who has acquired possession of the long-term skills, could be distracted by personal life, they might be overworked and bored of a particular kind of work, they might be in an environment unconducive to close concentration, they might have a grievance with their terms of employment, and so on.

An adult is never normally influenced for the better by repeated pestering, or any kind of training that has a remedial flavour about it.

If you're at someone's elbow and they're making new mistakes as you watch, you can rule out episodic neglect and carelessness.

If there's no seeming charade of incompetence, and no obvious reason for such a charade, then you can probably rule out anything wilful, too.

What's left is a person who doesn't have the attention to detail - the competence - necessary to perform the task you're asking them to perform. You can't alter that.

**Summary**

Of the report, either make the corrections yourself, delegate to someone with competence equal to your own, or (if possible) let the mistakes pass through without correction and let it reflect on the author.

And of the person, either accept their limitations and assign suitable work (or align your standards to their proven capability), or fire them.

**EDIT:**

I've re-read everything since my answer yesterday.

As an alternative interpretation, have you considered whether your expectations are reasonable, and the comments you make (and corrections you demand) worthy of the attention?

*50 comments* for a single document is an extremely large number of corrections. It must be quite some labour on your part just to enumerate and describe the locations of these errors.

Unless the writer has solicited that kind of detailed scrutiny (akin to a commercial publisher's pre-press review), or unless you are attempting to make an extremely powerful point yourself about the rank inferiority of a document (effectively using the process as a dressing down) - and it's not clear that either of these is actually the case - then there's always a possibility that you're fussing about a far higher standard than your staff can set, and that you're demoralising your staff further under the guise of attempting to teach them a standard that they aren't able or willing to meet.

Answer (score 3):

The situation described sounds less like a disability of the person, or carelessness, and more like [malicious compliance](https://www.reddit.com/r/maliciouscompliance/).

Dyslexia tends to promote itself primarily in spelling errors, where someone is unable to tell the difference between a word spelled correctly and a word spelled incorrectly.  Issues such as capitalizations, subject-verb agreement, and so on, are not what I would commonly associate with dyslexia.  Also, dyslexics tend to be forthcoming with their diagnoses in areas where it is relevant.  If this person was hired for a writing job and they were dyslexic, they would (usually. in my experience with dyslexic people I know) come out and tell you "I'm dyslexic, I may have trouble with this", rather than hide it from you.

Furthermore, if this person is a native English speaker, it would be more difficult actually to write "drivers intensifies" than "drivers intensify" or "driver intensifies"; you have to make a conscious decision/choice to break the habit of the normal way you speak/write to make such a mistake.

What this makes me think is that you're not telling us the whole story.  It sounds to me like one of the following 2 things are true:

1. This person is not a native English speaker.
2. This person is being spiteful and engaging in Malicious Compliance.

For 1), how did you determine this person is a native English speaker?  Did you make them take a test like TOEIC or TOEFL?  Those tests are notoriously bad at actually gauging English skill beyond basic comprehension.  A TOEIC or TOEFL score can tell you if the person knows basic English and can function in an English-speaking environment, but not something as granular as language level.  In order to tell if a person is a native English speaker, you should look at their background; someone from the USA, or Canada, or Hong Kong, or England, is more likely to be a native English speaker than someone from, for example, China or Spain or Egypt (just picking 3 non-English-majority countries at random).  If someone hasn't spent a long period of time in a majority-English-speaking locale, they're probably not a native English speaker.

For 2), can you think of a time in which you (or someone else on your team, or someone else in the company) was overly critical of this person's writing in the past?  This person is a native English speaker; they know how English works.  [Here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/190511/how-do-i-make-my-boss-understand-that-his-edits-to-my-writing-make-it-unreadable) is a similar question by someone on the other side of this issue; a native English speaker whose boss is continually and vehemently telling him to change his writing style to be worse, despite the boss not being a native English speaker.  In this case, your subordinate is caught between a rock and a hard place: He wants to make his writing good, which is his job, but also his boss, who can fire him for insubordination, is specifically telling him that his work is not good and to change it, to make it worse, because the boss thinks it's "better" (when it is, in fact worse, because the boss is not a native English speaker and doesn't understand the problem).  If this is something you may have done in the past, your subordinate may have simply given up: "I'm a native English speaker, but my boss, who can't speak English, thinks his English is better than mine; so I'll just lower my English level and make mistakes that my boss thinks are correct English to make him happy so he doesn't yell at me".

In the first case, you should probably hire an actual native English speaker, who has lived in the Anglosphere for an extended period of time and can actually speak native-level English.

In the second case, you might just be screwed.  If this person is engaging in malicious compliance over this, they are really mad at you, and there may be no way of rebuilding that bridge.  You can try having a chat with them, honestly and earnestly apologizing for the way you and others have acted, agree to assent to their authority in future regarding English language issues, and so on, but there's no guarantee they'll accept that if the damage done is too great.

Comment: Being able to speak intelligently in English and being able to write English are two very different skills. If this individual is from a region where English wouldn't be their primary language, from a very early age, they might have learned to speak and read the language but could very well have trouble writing in it. BLUF: *The error the individual described is making does not seem like an individual with their advertised skills in the English language.*

Comment: A native-level user of English should be able to do both.

Answer (score 2):

Does the colleague have a college degree?

I ask because someone who has been reminded to capitalise (*capitalize* US) the first letter of a new sentence but capitalises the offending word, "this", in the middle of a sentence must be completely unaware of the conventions of punctuation; *extremely* careless; unable to understand simple instructions; have a learning disorder or display passive aggressive behaviour. Randomly capitalising words in mid-sentence could be associated with [dysgraphia](https://www.readandspell.com/us/dyslexia-and-dysgraphia-difference), but I'd expect it in handwriting than in computer-written reports.

> …if I send them 50 comments, at least 10 of them will be simply missed, and for other 20 they will introduce new mistakes.

Fifty corrections is a lot! Whenever I help Italian students at level B2 and C1, write essays and reports in English, I don't think I have ever pointed out so many errors.  Was it hyperbole or does the OP frequently identify between 40 and 50 issues that need fixing? Perhaps they could focus on the most egregious ones, and suggest the person use a spell-checker to weed out the obvious misspellings.

When the colleague, an English native-speaker, receives the grammar, spelling corrections and notes about priority does he or she apologise and promise not to make the same mistake in the future? In their place, other employees would be mortified and strive to *improve* or at the very least not repeat the same errors. **The colleague's *repeated* failure to identify that number of errors in their own writing may suggest a learning disorder.**

One of the signs of dyslexia is the inability to summarise a long text, and a report is a type of summary. Among [other signs](https://www.healthline.com/health/dyslexia-in-adults), the following could indicate dyslexia in an adult:

- having difficulty focusing on one task
- avoiding meetings that are about planning
- becoming overwhelmed if asked to fill out a lengthy form
- overreacting to your mistakes
- imposing strict rules on yourself
- learning better visually or through hands-on experience
- being easily affected by stress
- having low self-esteem

There is no shame in having dysgraphia or dyslexia;
with professional support and training, adults who experience difficulty in reading and writing texts such as summaries, can be taught to overcome these difficulties and make significant progress. But unless the employee admits to experiencing difficulty in reading and writing, despite his or her attempts to produce writing that is accurate and grammatical, their supervisor (the OP) might be left with no other option than to fire him or her.

Comment: The most obvious explanation for capitalising mid-sentence words, is that the person used the Find+Replace All functionality of a word processor.

Comment: @Steve Ah, very possible. Well spotted.  But when reading back the report, shouldn't the person identify and see the word capitalised in mid-sentence. Unless they don't bother rereading it?

Comment: Well I suspect they're not going to use Replace All as a shortcut, then re-read every word of the document anyway. It's undoubtedly careless, but it's as capable of being a sign of someone worn out, as of someone allocating too little of their attention to it. So identifying it as careless doesn't really clarify a cause or a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, they do have a college degree. 50 mistakes is not a hyperbole, but for your reference, it's a big 30 page technical document, so a lot of these mistakes I point out have nothing to do with grammar. Sometimes I would say "please describe these 3 items as well", and then they just describe 1 or 2 of them. They always miss something.

Answer (score 1):

Go to their manager and explain the situation, that this process should be simple and works for everyone else but for some reason breaks down with this colleague. Like you said it could be something personal or disability related, you don't necessarily need the answer as to why this behavior happens you just need to make sure that the manager is aware of it if they aren't already, so they can provide them with any support needed. I am not sure what the team composition at your company looks like, but you can also run this by your manager (if they are different people) first to make sure you are not accidentally offending anyone by discussing a colleagues performance with their manager.

Otherwise I would recommend making small changes such as capitalizing a letter or pluralizing a word yourself. Instead of sending them "this word is singular make it plural" send them the change with "changed this wording to be plural." This should reduce the problem, which is that this process is taking up more of your time than it should.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Sorry if i wasn't explicit enough, but I'm their manager. Of course there are other higher ups I could complain to though. Regarding fixing small issues myself - I think that would just make the problem even worse, since now they know that they can be careless and their mistakes will be fixed by others. The goal of such review system is so others learn from their mistakes and hopefully don't repeat them again.

Comment: @user1880405 - As their manager, you should set your expectation that their work shouldn't have errors, or if they do have errors, set the number of errors contained in the document.

Comment: @user1880405 ah. well then my answer is definitely less useful haha.

Comment: @Donald Of course such expectation is set. At the very least that is implied isn't it? Considering that each document is reviewed and every single mistake is explicitly send back to them in order to get resolved. Every time I am asking them why so many of my comments are being ignored or not resolved properly, so I wouldn't have hard time believing this person does not understand that it's expected of him not to have errors.

Comment: @user1880405 - People have different types of communication methods.  Some individuals require explicit directions, while other can take actions, with just indirect statements. Have you explicitly set your expectations by indicating how many errors you will find acceptable? While I work intendent fairly well, if you require me to do something I require you tell me exactly what you want. So what you describe honestly isn't all that implied, but it's fairly clear, the individuals written English skills are not up to your standards.